# Multiple Match with Cypher is super slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I started with Cypher yesterday and went into a problem. My hierarchy structure looks like:

ReleaseCycle->Line->ProductSet

So "ReleaseCycle" are the fewest elements and in the hierarchy tree at the very top. The children from "ReleaseCycle" are "Line" and the children from "Line" are "ProductSet" which includes the most Data. All of them are related to "releaseTask" and i want to return all the releaseTask.

My cypher call at the moment looks like:

```
MATCH (a1:Line)<-[:contains]-(b1:ReleaseCycle{id:'xyz'})<-[c1:releaseTask]-(d1:Task)      
MATCH (a2:ProductSet)<-[:contains]-(b2:Line{id: a1.id})<-[c2:releaseTask]-(d2:Task)  
MATCH (b3:ProductSet{id: a2.id})<-[c3:releaseTask]-(d3:Task)

RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT {a:"cycle", task: d1, contributor: c1.contributor}),                             
COLLECT(DISTINCT {a:"Line", task: d2, contributor: c2.contributor}),
COLLECT(DISTINCT {a:"ps", task: d3, contributor: c3.contributor})
```

The problem is that it takes 5 seconds for the respond and it seems like there are entries missing. My result is only 800 but it should be 3000... Maybe because of the "Distinct" and Collect() but if i don't use them I get a timeout because the query takes too long.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If I understand correctly, from a specific `ReleaseCycle` you are searching all the sub-tree, and for each node of this sub-tree you want to have the linked `Task` . Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you PROFILE the query, you'll see that the number of records/rows being generated as the query executes is likely spiking. Cypher operations execute per record/row, so you're performing much more work than is needed.

The key with aggregation is to collect as early as possible (where it makes sense), and this will in turn reduce cardinality (the records/rows in the query) which means fewer operations needing execution and fewer redundant operations on the same nodes/data.

In your case, it makes sense to do this in steps, and to use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) as shorthand to match a pattern and collect results.

You can also reuse variables throughout your query instead of having to rematch to the nodes you already have (though WITH allows you to redefine what variables are in scope).

Try this one out, and if it gives good results, PROFILE it to see the difference:

```
MATCH (release:ReleaseCycle{id:'xyz'})
WITH release, [(release)<-[rel:releaseTask]-(task:Task) | 
 {a:"cycle", task:task, contributor:rel.contributor}] as cycleTasks   
MATCH (line:Line)<-[:contains]-(release)
WITH cycleTasks, line, [(line)<-[rel:releaseTask]-(task:Task) | 
 {a:"Line", task:task, contributor:rel.contributor}] as lineTasks
MATCH (prod:ProductSet)<-[:contains]-(line)
WITH cycleTasks, lineTasks, [(prod)<-[rel:releaseTask]-(task:Task) | 
 {a:"ps", task:task, contributor:rel.contributor}] as psTasks
RETURN cycleTasks, lineTasks, psTasks
```

Also, make sure you have indexes on the label/property combinations that you plan to use when looking up your starting node/nodes.

Comment: Wow the performance boost of this is amazing thank you very much for your good explanation!! I'm struggling right now with the result because after each iteration it starts with the Cycle again even with distinct there are a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: The structure is ReleaseCycle->Line->ProductSet and with the call I get all the tasks which are connected to them. First I get all the cycleTasks than all the tasks from the first line and finally from the first ProductSet. Than I get all the CycleTasks again followed by the first LineTasks again and the second ProductSet but i actually just need the second productsets than the rest is just repetition.

Comment: I think it returns which is called as: "cartesian product"